# как проверить наличие отличающегося атрибута элемента?

Tags: javascript

Есть див:

```
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="" > </div>
```

Как определить, есть ли у div атрибут, начинающийся с **data-**, но отличающийся от атрибутов «data-one» и «data-two» (т.е не заканчивающийся на «one» и «two») и если он есть удалить элемент?

Answer (score 1):

У элементов есть атрибуты вида **data-***. Все эти атрибуты лежат в `<Element>.dataset` и представляют из себя объект.

Что бы удалить атрибут, просто удаляем его, как из обычного объекта:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('tst');
console.log('До', div);
console.log('ДатаСет', div.dataset);
for (let val in div.dataset) {
  if (val !== 'one' && val !== 'two') delete div.dataset[val]
}

console.log('После', div);
```

```html
<div class="test" id="tst" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="222">Удаление лихних атрибутов *data-*</div>
```

UPD по комментарию

> а если необходимо удалить не атрибут, а конкретно этот Div

Для удаления самого DIV используйте метод **remove()**

```js
const div = document.getElementById('tst');
console.log('До', div);
console.log('ДатаСет', div.dataset);
for (let val in div.dataset) {
  if (val !== 'one' && val !== 'two') div.remove();
}
console.log('После', document.getElementById('tst'));
```

```html
<div class="test" id="tst" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="222">Удаление лихних атрибутов *data-*</div>
```

UPD по [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1534442/520560)

Если элементов может быть много с нужным классом и нет возможности добавить в нужный элемент уникальный id, то можно воспользоваться следующим скриптом, который выбирает все элементы по имени класса, а далее каждый проверяет на наличие атрибутов **data-** и если условие выполняется, то удалеяет элемент и останавливает внутренний цикл

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
divs.forEach(item => {
  for (let val in item.dataset) {
    if (val !== 'one' && val !== 'two') {
      item.remove();
      break; // Нет смысла дальше проверять на удаленном элементе
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="test2" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="">Не тот класс</div>
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two="11">Нет data-three</div>
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="">Будет удалено</div>
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-four="">Тоже удалено</div>
```

Comment: SwaD, а если необходимо удалить не атрибут, а конкретно этот Div?

Comment: @Алексей Дополнил ответ. Да, и обратите внимание, что для доступа к элементу, был добавлен атрибут **id**

Comment: SwaD, а без добавления id, т.е. по классу не выйдет удалить элемент?

Comment: Возможно рассуждаю как костыль, но наверное можно через класс добавить id и после через id удалить :/

Comment: @Алексей Выйдет. Можно использвоать `document.querySelector()` или `document.querySelectorAll()`, а так же `document.getElementsByClassName()`. Первый вернет один первый элемен со страницы, остальные вернут коллекцию найденных элементов. Таким образом, если на странице более одного элемента с таким классом, надо будет выстраивать дополнительную проверку

Answer (score 0):

```js
  window.onload = function() {
    var divsToRemove = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for (var i = 0; i < divsToRemove.length; i++) {
      for (let val in divsToRemove[i].dataset) {
        if (val !== 'one' && val !== 'two-test') {
          divsToRemove[i].remove();
        }
      }

    }
  };
```

```html
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two-test="11" data-three="222">к удалению</div>
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two-test="11">сохранить</div>
<div class="test" data-one="1" data-two="11" data-three="222">к удалению</div>
```

Comment: Обновил ответ. В вашем скрипте есть неточности...

Comment: немного переписал, но теперь удаляет вообще все div..

Comment: а ой, вроде работает

Comment: Зачем вы используете var? Советую отказаться от этого, т.к. [ключевое слово var устарело](https://learn.javascript.ru/var).